# Windows Phone 7, Conditional Statement for Stroke Color possible?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, colors, conditional-statements

I am having so much trouble with this little thing, and I am hoping someone can answer.

I have a rectangle named "Three" with a default `Stroke="#FF123123"` that if someone clicks on the rectangle, it changes the stroke color (the border) to

```
Three.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
```

If someone clicks on it again, I would like for it to change back to its original color of `Stroke="#FF123123"`. I already have the code for that and that is not a problem. THe problem is how do I create a conditional statement in order to change it back, provided it was changed in the first place?

I cannot do a conditional statement of:

"If (Three.Stroke == Colors.Yellow) {}"

as I receive the error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to
>   operands of type
>   'System.Windows.Media.Brush' and
>   'System.Windows.Media.Color'

Answer (score 1):

Keep an array of two brush instances somewhere. If the rectangle's brush is one of them, switch to the other (instead of creating a new instance on the spot).

The error is quite straightforward: you're trying to compare the brush itself to a possible colour for the brush. You **could** determine the colour of the current brush and compare it, but the above approach is probably simpler.

Comment: Hi Karl, could you please provide a coding example of how to do this? I'm learning C# while making this application, and as you might expect it's like slicing wrists.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but perhaps instead of a `Rectangle` you could use a `ToggleButton` and declaratively apply styling based on the `IsChecked` property?

Answer (score 0):

The `Stroke` property is of type `Brush`, for which `SolidColorBrush` is a subclass. If you want to access a property of `SolidColorBrush`, you need to cast the value of `Stroke` to a `SolidColorBrush`:

```
Color currentColor = ((SolidColorBrush)Three.Stroke).Color;

if (currentColor == Colors.Yellow) {}
```